# I want to have 3 div in a row in my page, i tried flex,grid,inline, but i am unable to do so

Tags: css, reactjs

[[image: i have attached the image i want and what i have][1]]I created a card component which has wrapper div to wrap cards in it, the cards are display fine 1 in a row, however I want to display 3 in a row and unable to do it. I have tried display flex to show 1 in a row.

**Cards component**

```
import React from "react";
import "../index.css";

const Card = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="cards">
        <div className="card">
          <img src={props.imgSrc} alt="Dark" className="card-img" />
          <div className="card-info">
            <span className="card-category">{props.cat}</span>
            <h3 className="card-title">{props.title}</h3>
            <a href={props.link}>
              <button>watch now</button>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export { Card };
```

**Index**

```
import react from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Whole } from "./Whole";
import { Cards } from "./learningReact/Cards";
ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <Cards />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

**css**

```
cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.card {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(248, 239, 248);

  border-radius: 10px;
}
.card img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Can you attach your desire result here?

Comment: "3 in a row" means horizontally or vertically?

Comment: 3 in a row or 3 column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use flex-basis:33%; for .card div tag and flex-wrap:no-wrap; & justify-content: space-between; for .cards div tag:

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 100px auto;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
}
.card {
  flex-basis:33%;
  height: 300px;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(248, 239, 248);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `justify-content: center` with `justify-content: space-between` inside `.cards` block and it will be displayed in a single row.

[output here](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/11879844?key=a86556d671e7a19ad8f31ee1d4c4bd76)

Comment: and how can i do so with grid display

Comment: not working yet it changed alignment to left from center thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.card-data {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: #000;
}

.card-data  div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 33%;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>

<div class="card-data">
  <div>Hello..</div>
  <div>Test...</div>
  <div>Content..</div>  
  
</div>
```

Comment: this works i figured out before but thanks